# Action on document.getElementById is not redirecting me to created upload link

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit-button

I have an HTML page where users choose files and upload them to a URL through pressing a submit button. This button redirects the user to the URL while also submitting the file to the URL. Currently, however, my page is not redirecting to the upload URL and only stays on the original HTML page, not submitting anything. I was considering removing `e.preventDefault` and `return false` from `submitForm` however they are needed for the code to function. What should I do?

HTML snippet:

```
<form method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id = finalsubmit onsubmit = "submitForm(event)">
    <label for = "myfile"><strong>Select a file to be uploaded:</strong></label>
    <input class = choosebutton type = "file" id = "myfile" name = "filename"><br>
    <input class = uploadbutton type = "submit" onclick="finalSubmission()" value = "Upload File">
</form>
```

Javascript snippet:

```
async function finalSubmission () {
    const accessKey = await assignSas(); // function to develop key
    let urlFinal = "https://<upload-link> + "?accesskey=" + accessKey;
    document.getElementById("finalsubmit").action = urlFinal;
}

async function submitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    await Promise.resolve();
    return false
}
```

Comment: `onclick` doesn't use `await`, so it's not waiting for the asynchronous call in `finalSubmission()` to finish.

Comment: Are you expecting `await Promise.resolve()` to wait for the promise in `finalSubmission()`? That's not what the function does.

Comment: How does the button redirect the user? It's setting the `action` of the form, but `submitForm()` ignores that because it uses `e.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the functions with `onclick` it doesn't await the functions. So if you use asynchronous code to change the `action` of the form, the form will be submitted before it finishes.

Using `e.preventDefault()` just prevents the form from being submitted automatically at all.

What you should do is update the action and then call `form.submit()` explicitly. You can do it all in one function.

```js
async function finalSubmission(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const accessKey = await assignSas(); // function to develop key
  let urlFinal = `https://<upload-link>?accesskey=${accessKey}`;
  e.target.action = urlFinal;
  e.target.submit();
}
```

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="finalsubmit" onsubmit="finalSubmission(event)">
  <label for="myfile"><strong>Select a file to be uploaded:</strong></label>
  <input class="choosebutton" type="file" id="myfile" name="filename"><br>
  <input class="uploadbutton" type="submit"" value="Upload File">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, you've helped me better understand how HTML works with your answer. I did not know that onclick does not await the functions, that is good to know.

Comment: In general, nothing automatically awaits any async operation.

Comment: Thank you again @Barmar. Again, it's good to know that nothing awaits async operations automatically. I am new to coding in HTML so it's good for me to know information like this.